# New Flutter app missing iOS and Android folder in the main directory

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, dart, flutter

I recently installed Android Studio to create a new Flutter app. I created a new application & there isn't an iOS or Android Folder (as you can see on the photo). Is this normal? Because when I see some others videos, these folders are in the main folder.

Also when I run `flutter doctor` in the terminal it fails with an error that the command is unable to find the file `pub.dart.snapshot`.

Thanks you & have a nice day :)

[image: Folder Screenshot]

Comment: I would recommend just going through the entire [flutter install/setup](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) process all over again. Don't skip any steps. While you shouldn't need to download everything again, you should make sure everything is in the right place. Good luck.

Comment: try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21859

Comment: Have you tried the workaround [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41552#issuecomment-566074395)? Also, it seems that [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685089/unable-to-create-flutter-project) is also related to yours.

Answer (score 1):

If you configured the Flutter project to only have web support initially, you can add Android/iOS configs at a later time by running `flutter create --platforms=android,ios [PROJECT]`. The command generates the missing Android/iOS files for the Flutter project.