# Unable to create flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

When running `flutter create` followed by project name, I receive this error:

```
Error: Error when reading '../documents/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/pub.dart.snapshot': No such file or directory
Running "flutter pub get" in pics...                                    
pub get failed (254; Error: Error when reading
'../documents/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/pub.dart.snapshot': No
such file or directory)
```

I'm trying to create a new flutter project in xcode. How would I fix this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use XCode as the IDE to build a Flutter app? The officially supported IDEs are [Visual Studio Code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code) and [Android Studio & IntelliJ](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio).

Comment: I usually use Android Studio but I want to learn how to use XCode. @JoãoSoares

Comment: That's great, but XCode is to build native iOS and macOS applications. Not Flutter applications. Regardless, the problem is likely something else, unrelated to the IDE. But I would strongly advise you to use one of the official IDEs. Building Flutter apps on other IDEs without plugin support is going to be a lot more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: Technically you can, because if you open the iOS project inside your Flutter app project and run the code, it will build. But if you are going to be coding Flutter in XCode without a supporting plugin like the ones that exist for VSCode and IntelliJ based IDEs, you are going to have a hard time.

Answer (score 4):

> '../documents/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/pub.dart.snapshot': No
>   such file or directory

It seems like there may be files missing from your Flutter SDK. There should be a file in the Flutter SDK at `bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/pub.dart.snapshot` but this error suggests it's missing.

The easiest fix may be to delete the `bin/cache` folder which will cause Flutter to re-download the Dart SDK and other components when you next run `flutter`. This may take a little while depending on your connection, but is the simplest way to ensure the `cache` folder is complete. I would suggest closing all IDEs/editors when doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue but the problem was windows defender at real time detection so the solution was to switch off it then create a project...